# How to get values of heading when a checkbox is clicked inside that div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs containing a `<h1>` tag and checkbox. I want to retrieve the value of the heading when the checkbox of that particular div is clicked. for example:

```
<div class="send">
  <h1>hi</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/>
</div>
<div class="send">
  <h1>welcome</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

How to get the particular heading value when the particular checkbox is clicked inside that particular div in JavaScript? Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function(){

if($(this).is(':checked')){

console.log($(this).prev('h1').text())

}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="send">
  <h1>hi</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/>
</div>
<div class="send">
  <h1>welcome</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

1. Use prev('h1') to get the h1 of the checked element

Answer (score 1):

You will need `change` and not `click` as event. In your case you can use `prev()`, because the element is just before it.

```js
$(".send input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).prev().text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="send">
  <h1>hi</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
</div>
<div class="send">
  <h1>welcome</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
</div>
```

If you just want the `value` whenever the `input` is `checked` you can use an `if` inside too:

```js
$(".send input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    if( $(this).prop("checked") ) {
        console.log($(this).prev().text());
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="send">
  <h1>hi</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
</div>
<div class="send">
  <h1>welcome</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**siblings()**](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function.

```
    $("input:checkbox[name='checkbox']").click(function{
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
      var h1tagText = $(this).siblings("h1").text();
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript Solution:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".send input[type=checkbox]");

for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++){
  inputs[i].addEventListner("change",function(e){
    var heading = e.target.parentElement.querySelector("h2").innerHTML;
    //do something with heading
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess that you want to get the value only when the checkbox gets checked and not unchecked.
This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            alert($(this).parent().find("h1").html());
        }
    });
});
```